# .net core httpClient calls fail randomly with many different error messages

Tags: c#, http, .net-core

I have an app that behaves fine most of the time, but I randomly see errors where the request does not complete. The error messages I've seen are:

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

> The SSL connection could not be established

> Response ended prematurely

> A task was cancelled

> The connection was closed by the remote host

These are sometimes nested as `InnerException` messages. When I run a curl script every 10 seconds all day long, I can't reproduce the problem. However, I made a dotnet core app on the same server and I was able to see this error happen by firing many requests at the remote API. So the error is somehow related to the dotnet core method of calling this remote API.

I am using the dotnet core HttpClient like so:

```
var response = await _HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I've tried every TLS version, I'm using `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in Startup, but I'm not sure what else I can do to find the source of this problem. I'm adding retry logic to prevent total failure, but I'd really like to know what is happening in the code to make this fail randomly.

Comment: What TLS version is allowed by the remote service?

Comment: The remote service recommends 1.3. So my code has: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: Is your failing request a GET?

Comment: Yes it’s a get request

Comment: If it is a GET then why don't you just simply retry?

Comment: I've added some retry logic, but making the user wait is a poor way to cope with this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. My HttpClient was experiencing ["socket exhaustion" under heavy loads](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

The solution for me was to make the HttpClient a singleton and reuse it

```
public class HttpClientSingleton
{
    private static HttpClient client;

    private HttpClientSingleton() { }

    public static HttpClient Client
    {
        get
        {
            if (client == null)
            {
                client = new HttpClient();
            }
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that this solution is not thread-safe.

Comment: Is the factory method better using DI? I've seen a pattern where the HttpClientFactory is used in lieu of my approach.

Comment: You can create a singleton instance like this if you want. You don't have to introduce DI just for this. I wanted to emphasise that this is not thread-safe. [Please check Jon Skeet's guidance about this topic](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton)